# How to make folding Origami animation

Tags: animation, workflow

I want to make an animation of folding origami, so I want to know how to animate the rotation of a plane around an axis.

Comment: *Very* good question. I've wondered the same thing before.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/161399/2214

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I remember making an animation folding a crane in the past.

It involved making a real crane, unfolding it then cutting a plane mesh where the folds are in the real one. You have to double up on each cut as real paper folds have a little thickness.

Then add an armature with a bone for each plane, joined at the doubled hinges, then animate the armature.

I'll see if I can dig up the blend file and provide a clearer explanation. The thing I remember most it's that it is not trivial! Don't expect it to be done in an hour.

Comment: Thank you!! I realized your helpful advice and I decided to make origami with your method.
I tried to fold a plane in half with armature, but I couldn't do it well. 
This is result.
[result](http://iup.2ch-library.com/i/i1125557-1391660742.jpg),
[Mesh](http://iup.2ch-library.com/i/i1125558-1391660786.jpg)

How do I set a bone to plane to fold?

You said folding Origami wasn't trivial, but I wanna never give up it, so I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I'm sorry, I could only fold in half. this is [result](http://iup.2ch-library.com/i/i1125571-1391666285.jpg). I didn't select vertex groups!

Comment: Could you provide stack.imgur-Links? These are unavailable any more.

Comment: curious on the latest as well for PlayGAMI.com

Comment: how did you do the non flat fold parts like the part where the crane expands out  in an inverted paper fold out?

Answer (score 3):

There is an addon called AnimAll that you may want to activate. [watch this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xlJ71XChDuY)

You may find that custom [transform orientations](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Transform_Orientations) can be helpful to define the centre of rotation.

Another tip is to select two vertices and then <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> Cursor to selected and set pivot point to 3dCursor. This really only helps if the line is parallel to an axis.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your advice!! I didn't know this addon at all, so I try it! thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question. I am not really sure what the best approach is. So I did some experimentation and this seems like one way to do it:

1. Start with a plane. Subdivide/Knife where you want to fold the sheet. Create a basis shape key.
2. Use a separate shape key to record each folding step. Subdivide/Knife the geometry as necessary as you go. Set Pivot Point to 3D cursor.
3. Throw in a Bevel modifier to create the 'crease' in the paper.
4. Animate the shape keys.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your advice!! I tried same way as yours the other day and rotation was success, but animation was failed.
In shape key animation, a rotating point passes through the shortest distance to a rotated point.