# How to unfold an entire mesh into a flat object? (Not UV Unwrap)

Tags: modeling

Is it possible to unfold the geometry into a plane without distorting the faces, Just like a paper cutoff inside blender?

Comment: **I just want to unwrap the mesh** For example if the mesh is cube. i want all of its 6 faces unwrapped as plane. But there should be no change in shape of it's faces. hope you understand. If you don't understand let me know I'll explain more with image

Comment: You can rig it and pose the rig in an unfolded position. Of course the more complex the model, the more difficult this becomes. Could work for low poly though.

Answer (score 1):

*Finally Found the answer*

Export the uv layout as a .svg file. Then import that .svg file back into blender. It will be a curve object so you will need to then convert it to a mesh (Alt+C)

Comment: Ah, so you ment like in ZBrush, where you can "unfold" your mesh to display the uv.

Comment: There is a "paperfold" addon (I don't know if it works still on current versions): https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/Paper_Model If you want to animate read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6767/how-to-make-folding-origami-animation

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2351/is-there-a-way-to-unfold-a-mesh

Comment: Just for fun you can watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iKMDESHjI1Q